# Finding the actual vector

Tags: linear-algebra

In a homework assignment, I have been asked to find the actual vector *v* when given basis coordinate [*v*]*B* = [5 -4 1]. It just wants my reasoning and doesn't want me to solve the problem. B = {[-1 0 1], [0 0 1/2], [3 -2 0]}.

I am seeking to understand how to do this. As of right now, I believe that a zero vector is involved somehow because to find the basis coordinates in another problem, I row reduced the given vector after setting it equal to a zero vector. Could someone guide me in the right direction to answer this question?

Comment: What is $B$?  The coordinates of $v$ rel the standard basis will be the matrix whose columns are the elements of $B$ applied to $\begin{pmatrix}5\\-4\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Sorry about that @ChrisCuster, I've added the vectors of B.

Comment: Sure.  So do you see what to do?  I will post an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I indicated in the comments, we get $\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&3\\0&0&-2\\1&1/2&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}5\\-4\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2\\-2\\3\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Seeing this, I now have NO idea whatsoever why I was confused as to what I should do. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The way I remember this is that, by applying the matrix to the standard basis, you get the elements of $B$, written in the standard basis.  Thus it's the transition matrix from $B$ to the standard basis. Note that $B$ expressed in terms of itself is the standard basis.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler than Chris's answer,
$$\mathbf{v}=5\mathbf{b}_1-4\mathbf{b}_2+\mathbf{b}_3$$
$$=5(-1,0,1)-4(0,0,1/2)+1(3,-2,0)=(-5+3,-2,5-2)=(-2,-2,3)$$